# comparing two strings and determining if they are equal

Tags: php

I have two strings that am trying to compare but it is displaying that they are not equal. What could be the problem? Here is the code that am running.

```
     <?php
        $x = "Come and enjoy the show.";
        $y = "Come and enjoy the show.";

       if (strcmp($x, $y)) {
          echo "They are the same.";
       } else {
           echo "They are not the same.";
       }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

*[strcmp](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strcmp.php)* - It returns zero on exact match & hence else condition will get executed in your case.

**Defination**: Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Change your condition with,

```
if (strcmp($x, $y) === 0) {
  echo "They are the same.";
} else {
  echo "They are not the same.";
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wgkw14)**.

Comment: Thank you for the help. but effect would it have if i used the negation operator(!). Like 'if (!strcmp($x, $y))'. @Rikesh

Comment: You can do that just change the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp can returns multiple values.

From the doc :

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

So, instead try this code :

```
   if (strcmp($x, $y) === 0) {
      echo "They are the same.";
   } else {
       echo "They are not the same.";
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

strcmp function
Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

```
if (strcmp($x, $y) === 0) {
          echo "They are the same.";
       } else {
           echo "They are not the same.";
       }
```

Comment: You should say more about _why_ that is a solution…